# Flask script returns to root rather than remain on the upload page since moving to an app

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask script with an @app.route('/') that displays a file upload form and then uploads a CSV file and creates a page of stats from @app.route('/', methods =['POST'])

This works absolutely fine when I am using a simple Flask script but I have now moved this to an app, added user authentication and also moved the file upload from / to /upload.

The issue I am now getting is that when the file is uploaded. Rather than displaying the stats on /upload, I'm redirected back to / and I see the following, I assume GET in the address bar:

```
http://192.168.19.180:5000/upload?file_name=uploadedfile.csv
```

The file is still being uploaded to the static/uploads directory and the output_csv_header() function in @main.route('/upload') is being called as I see other processes running. It's just redirecting to / and not remaining on /upload where I had expected to see my stats.

I have been all over this, spent hours searching and have hit a brick wall. I'm assuming I've missed something obvious with the routes and would appreciate some pointers please.

I've left out all of the functions that are in modules.py as they just work with the data.

Thank you for your help.

```
#  Displays home page
@main.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

#  Displays a list of team members
@main.route('/teamlist')
@login_required
def teamlist():
    users = User.query.all()
    return render_template('teamlist.html', users = users)

#  The route that takes the POST and uploads the file
#  The file is still being uploaded but it's redirecting to / instead
@main.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def uploadfiles():
    """ Upload csv file """
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    file_name = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
    if file_name != '':
        file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]
        if file_ext not in app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS']:
            abort(400)
        uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], file_name))
    return redirect(url_for('main.upload', file_name=file_name))


#  If files present in uploads dir it runs output_csv_header func
#  If not it displays a message and the upload form
@main.route('/upload')
def upload():
    # Test if there are any files present in the uploads directory
    form = FileUpload()
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    #if os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH']):
    if os.listdir('app/static/uploads'):
        #files = os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'])
        files = os.listdir('app/static/uploads')
        csv_file_to_read = files[0]
        return output_csv_header(csv_file_to_read)
    else:
        message = Markup("<i>No Files present, please upload a Response Summary csv file</i>")
        return render_template('upload.html', file=message, form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return `render_template('upload.html', file=message, form=form)` instead of the redirect in the `POST` method.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but the page now just reloads when I submit the form.

Comment: Yes, that is what you want to happen, right? What are you expecting other than a reload?

Comment: I had expected it to display all the data from the csv as before but that is perhaps assuming too much. let me strip my code out and just get it to display a simple parameter to the template to see if that at least works.

Comment: If you want to display the data that you just uploaded, then you have to create a new route that does that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks to your reply, I went over the code again and spotted something that I'd missed in the first 3+ hours of staring at it. So thank you. I'm all sorted!